# nth-child's child is not shown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

There is a number of dynamically generated divs with hidden child. I need to display a the hidden child only in certain children (i really don't know how to word it better :) )

Here is the html of it

```
<div class="totalwrap">
   <div> a bunch of content</div>
   <div class="dynamicallygenerated">
      <div class="hiddenchild"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="dynamicallygenerated">
      <div class="hiddenchild"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

css

```
 .hiddenchild {display:none;}
```

and jquery

```
$(".totalwrap .dynamicallygenerated:nth-child(2) .hiddenchild ").css('display','block');
```

what did i miss?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it with CSS instead. There's no need to use jQuery for this.

```css
.hiddenchild {
  display: none;
}

.dynamicallygenerated:last-child .hiddenchild {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="totalwrap">
   <div> a bunch of content</div>
   <div class="dynamicallygenerated">
      1
      <div class="hiddenchild">Hidden child of 1</div>
   </div>
   <div class="dynamicallygenerated">
      2
      <div class="hiddenchild">Hidden child of 2</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `:eq()` insted of `nth-child()`

```
$(".totalwrap .dynamicallygenerated:eq(0) .hiddenchild").css("display","block");
```

what you have done is right I think the problem is something else